# railsのmigrationのcolumnに指定できるtypeの一覧は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Rails ガイド Active Record マイグレーション](https://railsguides.jp/active_record_migrations.html)には載っていなくて、信頼できる情報源を探しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails 6.0.3.1時点で、

- :primary_key
- :string
- :text
- :integer
- :bigint
- :float
- :decimal
- :numeric
- :datetime
- :time
- :date
- :binary
- :boolean

ソース: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column